# Is there a best time of the day to measure blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure

Does it even matter if I measure my blood pressure at night or in morning or during lunch time?

What is the best time of the day to measure blood pressure?

Comment: <Comments removed> Comments are not for answering questions. If you would like to provide an answer, please use the answer space so that the information can be properly vetted by voting.

Comment: Are you trying to maximize accuracy, or are you trying to cheat and get as high or as low a reading as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blood pressure of a person varies throughout the day. This is attributed to numerous factors including stimuli from your sorroundings. As an innate tendency of the body. blood pressure is lower at night when you sleep, and is higher when you wake up in the morning. It continuously increases(roughly) as the day progresses.

So there is no one best time to measure your blood pressure. If what you are looking to do is to monitor your blood pressure, then it is important that you measure it at the same time everyday - at whatever time of the day it is. If what you are trying to get is an accurate measurement, then you are better of measuring it at two different times of the day(in the morning and in the evening) and taking an average, or measure it at two different times and report the readings along with the time of the day the measurement was taken. If you are on any medication to control your blood pressure, then you should measure your blood pressure once in the morning before taking any medications and once in the evening (assuming that you take medication in the morning). However, your doctor may specifically ask you to measure your blood pressure at a particular time of the day. That is because he is interested in that particular value for some reason.

References :

1. [Short- and Long-Term Blood Pressure Variability](http://hyper.ahajournals.org/content/60/2/512.full.pdf)
2. [High blood pressure (hypertension)](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/high-blood-pressure/in-depth/high-blood-pressure/art-20047889?pg=2)